# Global name not defined in classes

Tags: python, class, object

I am having a problem with an error saying global name not defined in this program. I have tried everything I can think of to debug this and I am still without luck. I am new to object oriented programming so any help fixing it is appreciated.

CODE:

```
def main():

    ford=Car(2008,mustang)
    count=0

    for count in range(5):
        ford.accelerate()
        count+=1
        print("The speed is : "+ford.get_speed())

    for count in range(5):
        ford.brake()
        count-=1
        print("The speed is : "+ford.get_speed())



class Car:

    def __init__(self,model,carMake):
        self.__yearModel=model
        self.__make=carMake
        self.__speed=0

    def set_Model(self, model):
        self.__yearModel=model

    def set_Make(self,carMake):
        self.__make=carMake

    def get_Model(self):
        return self.__yearModel 

    def get_speed(self):
        return self.__speed

    def get_make(self):
        return self.__make

def accelerate(self):
        return self.__speed+5

    def brake(self):
        return self.__speed-5
```

Comment: Please post the complete error message.

Comment: Apart from the unindented `accelerate`, I don't get any error messages,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an indentation error in your code with the `accelerate` method. Here is the proper code: Please also see all the other edits I've made in your code (commented):

### WORKING DEMO


    def main():

```
    ford=Car(2008,'mustang')       #mustang should be a string (in '')
    count=0

    for count in range(5):
        ford.accelerate()
        count+=1
        print("The speed is : "+str(ford.get_speed()))   #you must cast the int as str

    for count in range(5):
        ford.brake()
        count-=1
        print("The speed is : "+str(ford.get_speed()))   #you must cast the int as str

class Car:

    def __init__(self,model,carMake):
        self.__yearModel=model
        self.__make=carMake
        self.__speed=0

    def set_Model(self, model):
        self.__yearModel=model

    def set_Make(self,carMake):
        self.__make=carMake

    def get_Model(self):
        return self.__yearModel 

    def get_speed(self):
        return self.__speed

    def get_make(self):
        return self.__make

    def accelerate(self):
        self.__speed += 5           #you should actually increment your speed instead of returning it

    def brake(self):
        self.__speed -= 5           #you should actually decrement your speed instead of returning it


main()           #Call the main() method to make the script actually run
```

Comment: Thanks, I got all of these edits done, it turns out the '' around mustang was what I needed to make it run, but now it is just spitting out zeros